# ajax data[0] is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sqlsrv

I use ajax to get the number of rows (COUNT(*)) from a sql query in php.

The JSON return in Firefox-Network tab is:

[{"number":2}],

(the 2 is without quotes).

But in "ajax success" , when i try to get the value (2) from data[0]["number"] or data.length,it returns "undefined".

It works only if i parse JSON as object.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'queries.php?q=count',
        type: 'post',
        //data: data,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 

        //var dataobject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        //console.log(dataobject);
        //var var2 = dataobject[0].number; ---->THIS WORKS!
        //alert(JSON.parse(data).length); ---->THIS WORKS!

        //console.log(data.length); ---->Undefined 

        console.log(typeof data); ---->string
        console.log(data[0]["number"]);---->Undefined,i want this to work!!! 

      }
});
```

Thw SQL i use in php is :

```
      switch ($_GET["q"]) {

      case "count":
      $sql = "SELECT count(*) as number from 
            (SELECT Employees.emp_username, .............
                    where Employees.emp_username = ? and Year(emp)=2016  and    Month(emp)= MONTH(getdate()) ) as rows1 ";

      $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql , array(&$_SESSION["username"] ));
      break;

      default: header("Location: index.php"); }


      if( !$stmt ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
      sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
      $rows = array();

      if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
      while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $rows[] = $row;  }

     } else{
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   } 

     print json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: in php you have to send data with json_encode or you have to parseJSON in javascript, because javascript don't know it's a json object and takes as string that returns from php.

Comment: I see that the JSON returned is a string.

But i have used this ajax-php-sql code in other apps and it was ok,without the need to parse the returned JSON first.The same happens when i use it in Jquery Datatables,i don't parse anything there.
I figure out that the problem is in the queries php file where the JSON output should or shouldn't be an object ???

If i write
         header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
before
            print json_encode($rows);
it works without the need to parse JSON .

Comment: My goal here is to point out where the error-problem is,in which piece of code? I believed that

         print json_encode($rows);

was enough for the JSON to be returned as object.

Comment: Mandeep,i use "print json_encode($rows);" in the last line of php file with sql query inside.Isn't this enough to return a valid json array?Someone explain why data[0][number] doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the data first, like you did with `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` or like in the alert `JSON.parse(data)`.

`data` is a string object, so when you access the element `[0]` you are getting the first character of the string. In your example: `[`. This is the first element of the **string** `[{"number":2}]`.

My suggestion is to apply [0]['number'] to `dataobject`, so your code should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'queries.php?q=count',
    type: 'post',
    //data: data,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) { 

    var dataobject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    console.log(dataobject[0]["number"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable type is string. You must parse it first.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'queries.php?q=count',
        type: 'post',
        //data: data,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 

        //var dataobject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        //console.log(dataobject);
        //var var2 = dataobject[0].number; ---->THIS WORKS!
        //alert(JSON.parse(data).length); ---->THIS WORKS!

        //console.log(data.length); ---->Undefined 

        console.log(typeof data); ---->string
data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data[0]["number"]);---->Undefined,i want this to work!!! 

      }
});
```